# Would integration with DPDK be beneficial in terms of performance for a DNS/DHCP/DNSSEC server?

Tags: linux, dns, dhcp, dpdk, dnssec

DPDK seems to provide an impressive performance boost for certain applications but I don't think servers will benefit nearly as much as things like routers/switches.

I haven't seen any mention of this being done or worked on so I am just wondering if it might would be worth working on.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK on its own only provides Layer 2 (i.e. Ethernet) access to a device. Thus you would first need to build a Layer 3 (i.e. IP) and Layer 4 (i.e. TCP/UDP) stack on top of it. You can use a KNI to get around this, but I don't think the (somewhat small) performance benefits will help in this case.

Even after getting all those layers it still probably wouldn't help much because odds are the packets getting into the application (the big thing that DPDK optimizes) isn't likely to be the bottleneck in something like DNS or DHCP (unless perhaps they were very simple, bare-bones implementations).

Some other caveats include needing to dedicate at least an entire core just to DPDK and, in most cases, DPDK will take over the entire interface, meaning you can't use it for anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is very helpful. I see that full TCP/IP stacks have been developed, 6wind is claiming a dramatic speed increase when performing the necessary calculations on the packet. Do you think that would be helpful in DNSSEC or is the overhead from TCP too small compared to the rest of the operation. Dedicating an entire core might not work well in a regular environment but when paired with SR-IOV, it might be a worth it trade off.